# gapi.client is undefined:Google plus api within a secha touch 2 application

Tags: javascript, google-api, sencha-touch-2, google-plus

My app complains that `gapi.client` is undefined and I don't know why. I have added the path to the api javascript file to my applications `app.json` file as
`"path": "https://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js"`.

The file loads correctly and I can see that `gapi` is getting defined but the `gapi.client` isn't getting defined. Any idea why? I have read the javascript api documentation at:https://developers.google.com/+/web/people/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`gapi` consists of different parts that can be loaded separately.

`plusone.js` includes support for various website badges/widgets, but doesn't include the client library.

If you want to have access to `gapi.client` you have to load the script `https://apis.google.com/js/client:plusone.js`